# jquery identity code generator

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here the context :

In a charity ball, people will log to a webpage, enter email and name, get a unique code. With that code they will go the special counter and get a thank you gift based on the fact they have a code, proof of their registration.

I was asked to build a simple webpage that would generate a alphanumeric code link and send to any email adress. That easy enough even for me.

What I do not know how to do is :

How do I create another page, where a person can enter the code to see if it's legitimate and give the prize to the person claiming it ?

They maybe solution already existing for that but I did not find it, wrong choice of word in Google I suppose.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question si too broad. Please do some reserarch and ask more specific questions.

Comment: My experience with database is limited, i do little programming so i know i will need one. To ask my question here is more in the sense of looking for solution already build tested and trusted by member of this community.

Comment: you dont really need a database, have a checking algoritm that ensures the code is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is to log the code to a database of some sort every time a code is generated, and then when the person goes to collect their gift, query the database to see if it's a code that's been generated before. If it is, you know it's legitimate.

You could also easily extend this to add the ability to mark codes as used, so they cannot be used to collect multiple gifts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to deal with a database, handle it like a serial number. Generate 1 or 2 sets of numbers that are serialized (`0019 - 0001`, `0019 - 0002`, `0019 - 0003`, etc.) then using those sets of numbers, generate 2 or more sets of numbers creating something like (`0019 - 0001 - 8276 - 7384`). Then, when a user passes in their number, take the first two numbers and generate that same number, then test that they are equal. This should be done server-side, if it is done client-side(with javascript) it will be very easy to crack (simply open the console).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to tinker with SQL or some 'real' databases, you could use a simple XML or JSON 'database'.
Just create a file and write an empty JSON-Array into it (`[]`). If you want to add keys, just read out the file, convert it into an php array by using `json_decode($file_content, true)` and write your new key into that array. Then you just have to write the array back into the file by using `json_encode($file_content)` and writing the result to a file.

If you want to check an entered key, just do the reading and converting thing and loop through your array to check for the key.

This will be too slow on a large scale, but for a small project it might be perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the [jQuery GUID helper](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/GUID_Helper) plugin regarding your question about client-side identity code generators. A GUID is a **Globally Unique Identifier**.

But you still have to decide how to store registered gift IDs, and how to check later that they're valid.